# Delete from List in WPF C# with Commands

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I want you to be able to click on the delete button and then click on a targeted annotation on the screen and remove the selected annotation, however all that happens currently is that it deletes ALL annotations instead of even being able to select one.

The button

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <customControls:ImageButton x:Name="BtnUndo" Height="30" Width="30" ImageSource="..\Images\undo.png" ToolTip="Undo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnUndo_Click" IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False"/>
                <customControls:ImageButton x:Name="BtnRedo" Margin="0,2,0,2" Height="30" Width="30" ImageSource="..\Images\redo.png" ToolTip="Redo" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnRedo_Click" IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False"/>
                <customControls:ImageButton x:Name="BtnClear" Height="30" Width="30" ImageSource="..\Images\clear.png" ToolTip="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnClear_Click" IsEnabled="False" Focusable="False"/>
                <customControls:ImageButton x:Name="BtnDeleteTarget" Margin="60,-60,0,2" Height="30" Width="30" ImageSource="..\Images\clear.png" ToolTip="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="DeleteTarget_Click" IsEnabled="True" Focusable="False"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

The event

```
private void DeleteTarget_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Common.Commands.CommandManager.Get().Do(new ClearTargetAnnotation(_annotationManager));
}
```

The Command

```
{
        private AnnotationManager _annotationManager;
        private List<Annotation> _annotations;

        public ClearTargetAnnotation(AnnotationManager annotationManager)
        {
            _annotationManager = annotationManager;
            _annotations = _annotationManager.GetAll();
        }
        public void Do()
        {
            foreach (var annotation in _annotations)
                _annotationManager.Remove(annotation);
        }

        public void Undo()
        {
            _annotationManager.Set(_annotations);
        }
    }
}
```

Remove method

```
public void Remove( Annotation annotation )
        {
            Monitor.Enter( _annotations );
            _annotations.Remove( annotation );
            Monitor.Exit( _annotations );

            annotation.OnMoved -= AnnotationMoved;
            Draw();

            if ( _annotations.Count == 0 )
                IsEmptyChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

> however all that happens currently is that it deletes ALL annotations

```
  public void Do()
    {
        foreach (var annotation in _annotations)
            _annotationManager.Remove(annotation);
    }
```

Seems pretty logical to me, calling this function will remove all the annotations. You should have a selected annotation that is updated from the view, and only remove that one from your list of annotations.

Note: As far as I can understand from your title, you're using WPF, in which case it could be useful to use a ObservableCollection instead of a List, as this will automatically update in the view if you change it.
More about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: "You should have a selected annotation that is updated from the view," what do you mean with selected annotation and how do I do this?

Comment: "I want you to be able to click on the delete button **and then click on a targeted annotation**"

When you click the button, the event is triggered, and all annotaion will be deleted, you need to change the logic to first select the annotation and then click the button, or your click should create a flag so that when clicking on some annotation it is excluded

Comment: @JsonDork You should keep track of which annotation is selected in a property and only remove that, instead of removing the whole list.